# Array one var in several vars

Tags: php, arrays, list

Greetins, I have a value in a SQL table, and I would like to array the results

Here is what I have:

```
$value = "{2-1}{3-1}{5-0}";
```

And I would like it like so:

```
$promo[2] = 1;
$promo[3] = 1;
$promo[5] = 0;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex and combine the matches together:

```
$value = "{2-1}{3-1}{5-0}";
preg_match_all( '/\{(\d+)-(\d+)\}/', $value, $matches);
$result = array_combine( $matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

This [produces](https://ideone.com/CvK5q0):

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [5] => 0
)
```